# Where/How to fetch current price of my new token on BSC?

Tags: solidity, bsc

I'm playing with solidity on BSC network...if I want to fetch the price of my test token, which service could I use? Can I write a function inside the smart contract of my token that retrieve the price or should I use some external API? It's important for me to retrieve the price as soon as the token is launched.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your token is tradeable on pancakeswap you can get your token price interacting with the corresponding `pancakePair` contract.

Comment: Thank you for your answer..where can I find the corresponding pancakePair contract after that my token is tradable on pancakeswap? Also, I need to implement this function on my smart contract right?

Comment: You can get it from pancakeFactory using the `pairFor` (or `getPair` or something like that, dont remember lol) function. And yes i guess you need to put this into your smart contract, that depends what you're trying to do with your price though.

Answer (score 0):

For a few months, I've been using the CoinBrain API. It's for free and they're providing near the real time market data (market cap, volume, liquidity, price) for all BNB tokens. Besides API, they're offering also some other stuff such as widgets or chatbots...

Definitely recommend to checking it out: https://coinbrain.com/dev-tools